# Adding older Google Play Services to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm using Android studio to develop a Google maps app. I'm trying to test it through a online emulator. My version of Google play services is 10.2.1, the emulator uses play services 10.0.84. There is no flexibility on there end. Is there a way to add or change my google play services to match the one they are using?I looked in dependencies under project structure, but I didn't see a way to add additional services. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your Google Play dependencies to match whatever version you feel like. Example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.2.1'//Replace 10.2.1 with 10.0.84 or whatever version you want
```

This is an example using play-services-games, but you can either use the full library or each individual dependency. It will work, as long as you change ALL the dependencies using play services to the same version

Comment: thanks for the reply, but Im gettingf a gradle build error when I try that: error 29,13 failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.84